# Does cosmos db cache results?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Does cosmos db cache the results? i.e. If we query cosmos db repeatedly for the same id, will we see the response time decreasing.
I tried hitting cosmos db with the same id and observed response times of  500ms, 300ms, 31ms, 240ms,355ms respectively. As you can see the response time was all over the place and i could not draw any conclusions.

Comment: Cosmos DB does not cache results. It is impossible to answer your question with the information given. Can you please provide more details including a sample document, the query in question, and your indexing policy.

Answer (score 0):

You probably experienced faster response time because query plans were cached. I think in your case there time was lowered for `query compile time` and `query plan build`. You wouldn't be able to lower the `write output` time since it's time it takes to copy the data.

I was not able to find any information that ComosDB caches the query results, so I wouldn't assume so.

You can look at the query metrics by using the .NET client [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics).